# How to get date when photo is clicked from android phone and is transferred to iPhone via Xender?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, photos.app, android

I have clicked few pictures from my android phone few months back. Today when I transferred those photos to my iPhone, it shows me created date as today. Is there a way in iPhone to get actual created date (The date when photo is clicked from android phone)?

Answer (score 1):

- Zip photos on Android phone by using a file explorer app on Android phone.
- Transfer zip file to iPhone.
- Unzip on iPhone by using an app (iZip, Winzip...). If you don't want to install third party app, you can send zip file via mail to iPhone.

Comment: I think you're answering "how do I transfer photos and keep the original metadata?", which is different to this question: "having already transferred photos to my iPhone from Android, how do I find the original metadata?"